# Deriving addition from various other operations

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

## problem

I need to derive addition and/or subtraction from a limited set of mathematical operations:

## limitations

- I can do arithmetic with constant values e.g. `x * 2` and `x + 2` are possible but `x * y` or `x + y` are not possible. Hence why I’m asking this question
- I can evaluate some trigonometric functions including sin(x), cos(x), arctan(x), and also csc(x), sec(x), and any others that can be derived from a combination of the listed functions above and below
- Some other non-trig functions that are available include log(x), ln(x), sqrt(x), 1/x, x^2, e^x, and 2^x. These are done via interpolated lookup tables and not actual mathematical operations

My first thought was to make use of a^2 + b^2 = c^2

If one can derive c from a and b via trigonometric functions given the limitations then that’s one possible solution

Alternatively, if multiplication or division is derivable from these operations that’s just as good!

Comment: This is not "a very dumb question". It's quite interesting how the evaluation of certain expressions is determined by knowing how others are evaluated. Certain specialized algorithms in computer science are built on calculating a familiar expression *but not in the usual way*.

Comment: Your comment about "multiplication ... just as good" suggests that you understand how having access to mutually inverse $\log$ and $\exp$ allow you to convert addition to multiplication and vice versa: 
$$
x \cdot y = \exp(\ln x + \ln y)
$$
(for $x, y > 0$) or
$$
x + y = \ln(\exp x \cdot \exp y)
$$
for any $x, y$.

Comment: What you ask is impossible to achieve if all you allowed to use are one variable functions, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your post to explicitly present a specific Math problem that you are having trouble with.  It is important that your post also include all of your partial work, in as well organized a manner as possible.  Then, someone can post an answer to the specific question, and you can learn from the answer.  Then, if need be, rinse and repeat with a $2$nd **totally separate** MathSE posting.

Comment: I’ll update this question to be more comprehensive once I have access to my computer. Thanks for the advice! And yes I did plan on using logs to determine one given the other. I just need one foot in the door